# Bug with hover effect after activating a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to learn basics for web development (HTML, CSS and JS), so I've been trying my chances on making a working apple calculator. Everything has been working fine, until I noticed a small bug.

At the very beginning, the hover effect over the operation buttons works pretty fine, when I hover the color becomes brighter. When I press the button, the button becomes even more bright and keeps it that way until the user inputs another number (or 'equal' button) to operate with previous number. After that, the operation buttons goes to it's normal color. Until then, everthing is fine, but I noticed that after the user has pressed a button and made it's operation, the hover effect doesn't work anymore, and when the mouse hovers over it, it doesn't change it's color anymore.

Here it's all the code I've written:

```
//HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Calulcadora
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="botonesCalculadora.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="calculadora">
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <p class="barra-resultado" id="result">0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <button class=grey href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('especial', 'resetear');"> AC </button>
            <button class=grey> &#177; </button> <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
            <button class=grey> &#8274; </button> <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
            <button class=orange id="division" href="#"
                onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'division'); contadorOperacion = 1;"> &divide; </button>
        </div>
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '7');"> 7 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '8');"> 8 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '9');"> 9 </button>
            <button class=orange id="multi" href="#"
                onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'multi'); contadorOperacion = 1;"> &times; </button>
        </div>
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '4');"> 4 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '5');"> 5 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '6');"> 6 </button>
            <button class=orange id="suma" href="#"
                onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'suma'); contadorOperacion = 1;"> &plus; </button>
        </div>
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '1');"> 1 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '2');"> 2 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '3');"> 3 </button>
            <button class=orange id="resta" href="#"
                onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'resta'); contadorOperacion = 1;"> &minus; </button>
        </div>
        <div class="linea_botones">
            <button class=blackZero href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '0');"> 0 </button>
            <button class=black href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '.');"> . </button>
            <button class=orange id="igual" href="#"
                onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'igual'); contadorOperacion = 1;"> = </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="calculadora.js"></script>
</body>



</html>



//CSS

button {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    border-radius:32px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    transition: filter 0.15s;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: brightness(117%);
}

button:active {
    filter: brightness(135%);
}

.orange {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
}

.black {
    background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
    color: white;
}

.blackZero{
    background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
    color: white;
    width: 138px;
    padding-right: 86px;
}

.grey {
    background-color: rgb(159,159,159);
    color: black;
    
}

.linea_botones {
    
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 0;
    
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.barra-resultado {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 64px;
    width: 265px;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.calculadora {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;

}



//JAVASCRIPT 

let numeroOperar = null;
let numeroOperacion = null;
var operacion = null;
var operacionAnterior = null;
var flagOperacion = 0;
var digitosIngresados = 0;
let resultado = document.getElementById("result");
let resultadoOperacion = 0;

function seleccionarBoton(tipo, valor) {
    switch (tipo) {
        case 'numero': //Revisar casos de uso: "Poner dos veces punto decimal", "Oprimir dos veces una operacion"
            if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor == '0') {
                resultado.innerHTML = '0';
                numeroOperacion = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor != '0') {
                resultado.innerHTML = '';
                resultado.innerHTML = valor;
                numeroOperacion = parseFloat(valor);
                digitosIngresados++;
                break;
            }
            if (digitosIngresados > 0) {
                resultado.innerHTML = resultado.innerHTML + valor;
                numeroOperacion = (numeroOperacion * 10) + parseFloat(valor);
                digitosIngresados++;
                break;
            }
            break;

        case 'operacion':
            operacion = valor;
            console.log("Contador: " + flagOperacion);
            
            if (flagOperacion == 0) {
                numeroOperar = numeroOperacion;
                try {
                    resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
                } catch (error) {
                    //Vacío -> Que no haga nada
                }
                alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
                operacionAnterior = operacion;
                digitosIngresados = 0;
                flagOperacion = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (flagOperacion == 1) {
                switch (operacionAnterior) {
                    case 'suma':
                        resultadoOperacion = sumarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
                        resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
                        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
                        resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
                        numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
                        break;
                    case 'resta':
                        resultadoOperacion = restarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
                        resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
                        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
                        resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
                        numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
                        break;
                    case 'multi':
                        resultadoOperacion = multiplicarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
                        resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
                        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
                        resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
                        numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
                        break;
                    case 'division':
                        resultadoOperacion = dividirDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
                        resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
                        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
                        resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
                        numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
                        break;
                    case 'igual':
                        flagOperacion = 0;
                        break;
                }
                digitosIngresados = 0;
                operacionAnterior = operacion;
            }

            break;

        case 'especial':
            if (valor == 'resetear') {
                resetearCalculadora();
            }
            break;
    };
}

function resetearCalculadora() {
    digitosIngresados = 0;
    flagOperacion = 0;
    resultado.innerHTML = '0';
    numeroOperacion = 0;
    numeroOperar = 0;
    if (operacion == null) {
        operacion == 'suma';
    }
    resetearBoton(operacion);
    operacion = null;
}

function alternativaResetearCalculadora() {

    location.reload();
}

function resetearBoton(palabra) {
    botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
    botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "none";
}

function alterarBotonOperacion(palabra) {
    if (palabra == 'igual') {
        return;
    }
    operacion = palabra;
    botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
    botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "brightness(135%)";
}

function resetearDuranteOperacion() {
    as;
}

function sumarDosNumeros(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}

function restarDosNumeros(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
}

function multiplicarDosNumeros(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
}

function dividirDosNumeros(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
}
```

I was expecting that after I used the button, it will still keep the hover effect. After one use of every operation button, it doesn't apply the hover effect anymore. This problem only happens in operation buttons, nor numbers or clear button act this way

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the shortest code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please provide your debugging details in form of a [repro] (`Ctrl + M` or `<>` Button). Pay extra attention to the word **minimal**. I doubt that it is necessary (nor is it helpful)  to post a few hundred lines of code. Cutting your code down to the minimal part is the first step in debugging yourself!

Answer (score 0):

hover effect doesn't work any more because of

```
function resetearBoton(palabra) {
    botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
    botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "none";
}
```

when this func runs, it sets an inline-style(filter:none;) to the button and because the **inline-styles have higher priority than external style sheets**(botonesCalculadora.css), it overrides your

```
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: brightness(117%);
}
```

in botonesCalculadora.css

---

there's two ways to fix this

1 using classes

```js
let numeroOperar = null;
let numeroOperacion = null;
var operacion = null;
var operacionAnterior = null;
var flagOperacion = 0;
var digitosIngresados = 0;
let resultado = document.getElementById("result");
let resultadoOperacion = 0;

function seleccionarBoton(tipo, valor) {
  switch (tipo) {
    case "numero": //Revisar casos de uso: "Poner dos veces punto decimal", "Oprimir dos veces una operacion"
      if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor == "0") {
        resultado.innerHTML = "0";
        numeroOperacion = 0;
        break;
      }
      if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor != "0") {
        resultado.innerHTML = "";
        resultado.innerHTML = valor;
        numeroOperacion = parseFloat(valor);
        digitosIngresados++;
        break;
      }
      if (digitosIngresados > 0) {
        resultado.innerHTML = resultado.innerHTML + valor;
        numeroOperacion = numeroOperacion * 10 + parseFloat(valor);
        digitosIngresados++;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case "operacion":
      operacion = valor;
      console.log("Contador: " + flagOperacion);

      if (flagOperacion == 0) {
        numeroOperar = numeroOperacion;
        try {
          resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
        } catch (error) {
          //Vacío -> Que no haga nada
        }
        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
        operacionAnterior = operacion;
        digitosIngresados = 0;
        flagOperacion = 1;
        break;
      }
      if (flagOperacion == 1) {
        switch (operacionAnterior) {
          case "suma":
            resultadoOperacion = sumarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "resta":
            resultadoOperacion = restarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "multi":
            resultadoOperacion = multiplicarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "division":
            resultadoOperacion = dividirDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "igual":
            flagOperacion = 0;
            break;
        }
        digitosIngresados = 0;
        operacionAnterior = operacion;
      }

      break;

    case "especial":
      if (valor == "resetear") {
        resetearCalculadora();
      }
      break;
  }
}

function resetearCalculadora() {
  digitosIngresados = 0;
  flagOperacion = 0;
  resultado.innerHTML = "0";
  numeroOperacion = 0;
  numeroOperar = 0;
  if (operacion == null) {
    operacion == "suma";
  }
  resetearBoton(operacion);
  operacion = null;
}

function alternativaResetearCalculadora() {
  location.reload();
}

function resetearBoton(palabra) {
  botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
  // botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "none";
  botonOperacion.classList.remove("active");
}

function alterarBotonOperacion(palabra) {
  if (palabra == "igual") {
    return;
  }
  operacion = palabra;
  botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
  botonOperacion.classList.add("active");
  // botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "brightness(135%)";
}

function resetearDuranteOperacion() {
  as;
}

function sumarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}

function restarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
}

function multiplicarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
}

function dividirDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  transition: filter 0.15s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: brightness(117%);
}

button:active,
button.active {
  filter: brightness(135%);
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
}

.black {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: white;
}

.blackZero {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: white;
  width: 138px;
  padding-right: 86px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: rgb(159, 159, 159);
  color: black;
}

.linea_botones {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.barra-resultado {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 265px;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.calculadora {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculadora">
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <p class="barra-resultado" id="result">0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="grey" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('especial', 'resetear');">AC</button>
    <button class="grey">&#177;</button>
    <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
    <button class="grey">&#8274;</button>
    <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
    <button class="orange" id="division" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'division'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&divide;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '7');">7</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '8');">8</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '9');">9</button>
    <button class="orange" id="multi" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'multi'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '4');">4</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '5');">5</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '6');">6</button>
    <button class="orange" id="suma" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'suma'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '1');">1</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '2');">2</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '3');">3</button>
    <button class="orange" id="resta" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'resta'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&minus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="blackZero" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '0');">0</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '.');">.</button>
    <button class="orange" id="igual" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'igual'); contadorOperacion = 1;">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 removing style attribute from button in reset func not setting(`filter:none;`)

```
function resetearBoton(palabra) {
    botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);      function resetearBoton(palabra) {
    botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
//  botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "none";      /** remove this **/
    botonOperacion.removeAttribute("style");      /** add this **/
  }
}
```

```js
let numeroOperar = null;
let numeroOperacion = null;
var operacion = null;
var operacionAnterior = null;
var flagOperacion = 0;
var digitosIngresados = 0;
let resultado = document.getElementById("result");
let resultadoOperacion = 0;

function seleccionarBoton(tipo, valor) {
  switch (tipo) {
    case "numero": //Revisar casos de uso: "Poner dos veces punto decimal", "Oprimir dos veces una operacion"
      if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor == "0") {
        resultado.innerHTML = "0";
        numeroOperacion = 0;
        break;
      }
      if (digitosIngresados == 0 && valor != "0") {
        resultado.innerHTML = "";
        resultado.innerHTML = valor;
        numeroOperacion = parseFloat(valor);
        digitosIngresados++;
        break;
      }
      if (digitosIngresados > 0) {
        resultado.innerHTML = resultado.innerHTML + valor;
        numeroOperacion = numeroOperacion * 10 + parseFloat(valor);
        digitosIngresados++;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case "operacion":
      operacion = valor;
      console.log("Contador: " + flagOperacion);

      if (flagOperacion == 0) {
        numeroOperar = numeroOperacion;
        try {
          resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
        } catch (error) {
          //Vacío -> Que no haga nada
        }
        alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
        operacionAnterior = operacion;
        digitosIngresados = 0;
        flagOperacion = 1;
        break;
      }
      if (flagOperacion == 1) {
        switch (operacionAnterior) {
          case "suma":
            resultadoOperacion = sumarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "resta":
            resultadoOperacion = restarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "multi":
            resultadoOperacion = multiplicarDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "division":
            resultadoOperacion = dividirDosNumeros(numeroOperar, numeroOperacion);
            resetearBoton(operacionAnterior);
            alterarBotonOperacion(valor);
            resultado.innerHTML = resultadoOperacion;
            numeroOperar = resultadoOperacion;
            break;
          case "igual":
            flagOperacion = 0;
            break;
        }
        digitosIngresados = 0;
        operacionAnterior = operacion;
      }

      break;

    case "especial":
      if (valor == "resetear") {
        resetearCalculadora();
      }
      break;
  }
}

function resetearCalculadora() {
  digitosIngresados = 0;
  flagOperacion = 0;
  resultado.innerHTML = "0";
  numeroOperacion = 0;
  numeroOperar = 0;
  if (operacion == null) {
    operacion == "suma";
  }
  resetearBoton(operacion);
  operacion = null;
}

function alternativaResetearCalculadora() {
  location.reload();
}

function resetearBoton(palabra) {
  botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
  //  botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "none";  /** remove this **/
  botonOperacion.removeAttribute("style"); /** add this **/
}

function alterarBotonOperacion(palabra) {
  if (palabra == "igual") {
    return;
  }
  operacion = palabra;
  botonOperacion = document.getElementById(palabra);
  botonOperacion.style["filter"] = "brightness(135%)";
}

function resetearDuranteOperacion() {
  as;
}

function sumarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}

function restarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
}

function multiplicarDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
}

function dividirDosNumeros(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  transition: filter 0.15s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: brightness(117%);
}

button:active {
  filter: brightness(135%);
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
}

.black {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: white;
}

.blackZero {
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: white;
  width: 138px;
  padding-right: 86px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: rgb(159, 159, 159);
  color: black;
}

.linea_botones {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.barra-resultado {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 265px;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.calculadora {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculadora">
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <p class="barra-resultado" id="result">0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="grey" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('especial', 'resetear');">AC</button>
    <button class="grey">&#177;</button>
    <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
    <button class="grey">&#8274;</button>
    <!--Estos botones serán de broma-->
    <button class="orange" id="division" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'division'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&divide;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '7');">7</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '8');">8</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '9');">9</button>
    <button class="orange" id="multi" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'multi'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '4');">4</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '5');">5</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '6');">6</button>
    <button class="orange" id="suma" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'suma'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '1');">1</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '2');">2</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '3');">3</button>
    <button class="orange" id="resta" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'resta'); contadorOperacion = 1;">&minus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="linea_botones">
    <button class="blackZero" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '0');">0</button>
    <button class="black" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('numero', '.');">.</button>
    <button class="orange" id="igual" href="#" onclick="seleccionarBoton('operacion', 'igual'); contadorOperacion = 1;">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```